# Gradient linear css issue (plunker attached

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

I have a plunker to show my case - https://plnkr.co/edit/NUriO63pxAa0tUrMOuZa?p=preview

If you see the css code in it, i am using gradient linear to apply background color to div.

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, green);
```

With this css, i am able to see gradual change of color from red to green. All i want is 50% of the div to have red color and 50% of the remaining div to have green color.

Can anyone help me how to get this one. ?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, here is a answer if it helps someone in the future

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  red 50%,green 51%, green 100%);
```